# como creo un diccionario con cuatro listas

Tags: python, bucle-for, diccionarios

cuento con esta informacion para crear un diccionario:

Nombres=["Martín","Milú","Anastasia","Lupita","Tomasa","Pelusa","Genoveva","Motita"]

Tipos=["canino", "canino", "felino", "felino", "felino", "canino", "bovino", "roedor"]

Edades=[12, 9, 10, 8, 9, 2, 14, 1]

Pesos=[33, 26, 4, 5, 5, 6, 106.4, 0.34]

esta es la forma como intento crearlo a partir de las listas:

diccionario=({})

i=0

for i in Nombres:

listaXanimal=[]

listaXanimal.extend([Nombres[i],Tipos[i],Edades[i],Pesos[i]])

diccionario[str(i+1)]=listaXanimal
i=i+1
print(diccionario)

me sale el error:
listaXanimal.extend([nombres[i],tipos[i],edades[i],pesos[i]])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

necesito esta salida:

{'1': ['Martín', 'canino', 12, 33], '2': ['Milú', 'canino', 9, 26], '3': ['Anastasia', 'felino', 10, 4], '4': ['Lupita', 'felino', 8, 5], '5': ['Tomasa', 'felino', 9, 5], '6': ['Pelusa', 'canino', 2, 6], '7': ['Genoveva', 'bovino', 14, 106.4], '8': ['Motita', 'roedor', 1, 0.34]}

Comment: Estás sobrescribiendo la variable i dentro del bucle for. Es decir, i vale 0, pero luego cuando iteras sobre la lista de nombres, i pasa a tener de valor un nombre.

Comment: La solución: Cambia el nombre de la variable que está en el bucle for.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres hacer iteraciones multiples, te recomiendo inventigar mas sobre zip(), hace las iteraciones pero como tu deseas que se tenga un numero como llave del diccionario.

```
Nombres = [
    "Martín",
    "Milú",
    "Anastasia",
    "Lupita",
    "Tomasa",
    "Pelusa",
    "Genoveva",
    "Motita",
]

Tipos = ["canino", "canino", "felino", "felino", "felino", "canino", "bovino", "roedor"]

Edades = [12, 9, 10, 8, 9, 2, 14, 1]

Pesos = [33, 26, 4, 5, 5, 6, 106.4, 0.34]

d = list(zip(Nombres, Tipos, Edades, Pesos))
p = {}
for index in range(len(d)):
    p.update({f"{index}": list(d[index])})

print(p)
```

poniendo dentro de zip los objetos que deseas iterar, esto lo converti a una lista para poder sacar la longitud y agregar los indices, al final solo se crea una diccionario vacio y este se actualiza mediante cada iteracion.

Zip por defecto te regresa una tupla, solo se convirtio a una lista.

Comment: Zip NO regresa una tupla. Regresa un iterador.

Comment: También puedes usar enteros como índices, en vez de strings. Recuerda que los índices pueden ser cualquier objeto inmutable. Por cierto, también podías usar `enumerate`